# HttpClient not using cache on staging server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, dotnet-httpclient

I have an HttpClient being used in an MVC application created as below:

```
new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler()
{
    CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable)
});
```

I'm sending out a request, and getting a response back as below:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=3600
  Date: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 10:26:41 GMT
  Location: <snip!>/api/customers/TEST
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  Content-Length: 246
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 11:26:42 GMT
}
```

On my local it works fine, but on the staging server when calling the same urls the service is still getting hit; the cache is not being used.

The MVC site using the service is hosted on IIS7, when developing I'm using IIS Express.

Why would there be a difference between running it on my local machine (where caching works) and the staging server (where caching does not work), and how can I fix it so caching works in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this but, I believe that because HttpClient uses the WinInet proxy for caching purposes, it will not work when running as a service. I.e. under IIS.
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238425 for more details.

Comment: Interesting! So, the obvious next question is, how can I resolve this? Is there a different request handler that I can use perhaps? I'd rather not re-create http caching logic myself.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett. I've been working on a messagehandler based replacement for the wininet cache. https://github.com/tavis-software/Tavis.PrivateCache  Currently, there is only an InMemoryStore for the cache and it needs some work to make the store thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't really have time to contribute right now (wife's due date was yesterday!) but I'll certainly keep an eye on the project.